# Database Error with Codeigniter Project

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a website using codeigniter. When i move my site from local server to live server and making changes to the db file accordingly It still shows a database error 1146. Here is the error

A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'cinodext_webcm.DATA' doesn't exist
>
> SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE TYPE = 'MOVIE' ORDER BY ID DESC
>
> Filename: /home/cinodext/public_html/models/site_upload.php
>
> Line Number: 70

Any Help???

Comment: Looks like your `DATA` table doesn't exist

Comment: @NULL
I have checked my database and this table exists inside the database

Comment: If you move your website from Window to Linux server the table name becomes case sensitive. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Firs, check your DB setting in /applications/config/dababases.php.

Then, try to connect manually from the web server, and run the query:

```
mysql -h <hostname> -u <username> -p<password>
USE cinodext_webcm;
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `type` = 'MOVIE' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This should help you understand where the error is generated from.

Comment: the space in not obligatory

Comment: TIL - the space is optional for usernames ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection user's permissions.